# a echo server which handle clients with pool of thread

Tags: java, multithreading, server, synchronized

client connection works (I use telnet), but nothing happens when I write a message with any client - even the condition with empty char (for disconnection).
I don't understand why. I get capacity and port with args[], and I start the server.

I already tested a simpler version with just a server which can handle one by one client, and it works.

```
public class EchoClient extends Thread {
    EchoServerForPool serv;
    BufferedReader inchan;
    DataOutputStream outchan;
    Socket socket;
    int port;

    public EchoClient(EchoServerForPool serv) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.serv = serv;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Socket s;
        while (true) {
            synchronized (this.serv) {
                if (this.serv.stillWaiting() == 0) {
                    try {
                        this.serv.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                s = this.serv.removeFirstSocket();
                serv.newConnect();
            }

            try {
                inchan = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                outchan = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                String message = inchan.readLine();
                if (message.equals("")) {
                    System.out.println("fin de connection");
                    break;
                }

                outchan.writeChars(message + "\n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    s.close();
                    synchronized (serv) {
                        serv.clientLeft();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public class EchoServerForPool extends Thread {
        ArrayList<EchoClient> clients;
        ArrayList<Socket> sockets;
        Socket client;
        int nbLocalhost = 0;
        int capacity, port, nbConnectedClient, nbWaitingSocket;

        public EchoServerForPool(int capacity, int port) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.capacity = capacity;
            this.port = port;
            clients = new ArrayList<EchoClient>(capacity);
            sockets = new ArrayList<Socket>();
            for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++) {
                EchoClient ec_i = new EchoClient(this);
                clients.add(ec_i);
                ec_i.start();
            }
        }

        public Socket removeFirstSocket() {
            Socket res = sockets.get(0);
            sockets.remove(0);
            return res;
        }

        public void newConnect() {
            nbConnectedClient++;
            nbWaitingSocket--;
        }

        public int stillWaiting() {
            return nbWaitingSocket;
        }

        public void clientLeft() {
            nbConnectedClient--;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                ServerSocket serv = new ServerSocket(this.port);
                while (true) {
                    this.client = serv.accept();
                    synchronized (this) {
                        nbLocalhost++;
                        System.out.println(client.getInetAddress().getHostName() + "-" + nbLocalhost + " connected");
                        sockets.add(client);
                        nbWaitingSocket++;
                        notify();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class EchoPoolThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int capacity = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        EchoClient.EchoServerForPool serveur = new EchoClient.EchoServerForPool(capacity, port);
        System.out.println("start server");
        serveur.start();
    }
}
```

EDIT : the problem was I iterate with clients.size() which is 0 instead of capacity, for fill my clients list....

Comment: I think you should initialize the EchoClient class when a new socket is opened, not at startup. Also, are you sure all those synchronization blocks are needed? You may be dealing with a dead lock.

Comment: @devgianlu have you a example where i can have a dead lock ? i absolutely needed those two synchronized block, because all clients can access to the server attributes, and i have to protect them.

Comment: I can't debug the code for you (too much time consuming), you can usually find deadlocks by using breakpoints or simple `println` statements. Consider starting again from the code I provided you in the answer since your is pretty convoluted.

Comment: @devgianlu first, you can't say "i can't debug the code for you" if you not able to give a example of execution which gives a deadlock.. because I do not see it and i spend lot of time with theses programs. Secondly, in your code you create as much as thread as client connected, if no one of them disconnect from the server, and you add a new client, you extend the arraylist beyond the capacity i decide to declare. so basically, you created as many as thread as client, or i dont understand but this seems to be not good

Comment: @devgianlu i say this is not good because, here, the goal is to avoid to create as many thread as client connected, its incredibly ineffective and this is why i create a pool of thread..

Comment: You can use [this helper class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for that. Make your classes implement `Runnable` instead of `Thread` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I've refactored your code a little bit to have a working solution. You can work from there to create a pool, right now the number of clients isn't limited.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

/**
 * @author Gianlu
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int capacity = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        EchoServerForPool serveur = new EchoServerForPool(capacity, port);
        System.out.println("start server");
        serveur.start();
    }

    public static class EchoServerForPool extends Thread {
        private final int port;
        private final ExecutorService executor;
        private final ArrayList<EchoClient> clients;
        private int nbLocalhost = 0;

        public EchoServerForPool(int capacity, int port) {
            this.port = port;

            clients = new ArrayList<>();
            executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(capacity);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ServerSocket serv = new ServerSocket(this.port);

                while (true) {
                    Socket socket = serv.accept();
                    EchoClient client = new EchoClient(this, socket);
                    executor.submit(client);
                    clients.add(client);
                    nbLocalhost++;
                    System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress().getHostName() + "-" + nbLocalhost + " connected");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void terminated(EchoClient client) {
            clients.remove(client);
        }
    }

    public static class EchoClient implements Runnable {
        private final EchoServerForPool pool;
        private final Socket socket;
        private final BufferedReader inchan;
        private final DataOutputStream outchan;

        public EchoClient(EchoServerForPool pool, Socket socket) throws IOException {
            this.pool = pool;
            this.socket = socket;
            this.inchan = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            this.outchan = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    String message = inchan.readLine();
                    if (message.equals("")) {
                        System.out.println("fin de connection");
                        break;
                    }

                    outchan.writeChars(message + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            pool.terminated(this);
        }
    }
}
```